# Find cumulative distribution function of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Random variable X has uniform distribution on $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$. Find cdf of variable X. I mean i do not know how to treat this on such strange interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<0$, $F_X(x) = 0$,

For $0 \le x < 1$, $F_X(x) = x/2$,

For $1 \le x < 2$,  $F_X(x) = 1/2$,

For $2 \le x < 3$,  $F_X(x) = 1/2 + (x-2)/2$,

For $x \ge 3$,  $F_X(x) = 1$.

Comment: Explain please why we have the following results for $2 \le x \le 3$ and $1 \le x \le 2$?

Comment: For $2\le x < 3$, $f_X(x) = 0$, hence, technically, the corresponding integration yields $0$. It stems from the fact that this interval is not part of the support of $X$, while the (intuitive) meaning of cdf at this interval is the probability to receive a value which is less or equal to any $x$ in $2\le x < 3$, i.e., it includes all $[0,1]$, namely, the area under the curve, which is equal to $1/2 \cdot 1$.

Comment: I do not understand your answer, but why $(x-2)/2$? density for interval you wrote is $1/2$ not zero

Comment: @mkropkowski For $ 2 \le x < 3$,  $F_X(x)= \frac{1}{2} + \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{2}dt = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x-2}{2}$. You have to consider the $1/2$ from the first interval because it is a $\textit{cumulative}$ function.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The density function is
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x<0 \\
1/2, & 0\leq x \leq 1\\
0, & 1<x<2\\
1/2, & 2\leq x \leq 3\\
0,x>3
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: so will it be for $0 \le x \le 1$ something like $1/2t$? and for $2 \le x \le 3$ the same thing?  for certain below zero will be 0 and above 3 will be 1.

Comment: That's the idea (I guess you mean $\frac12x$). Integrate piecewise. $F_X$ will be flat over $[1,2]$ and then begin to rise again over $[2,3]$. It's actually piecewise linear and continuous, so you can figure it out without integrating, but you should try integrating piecewise to evaluate $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)\;dt$, noting that $f_X$ is piecewise constant on various intervals. The particular intervals involved will depend on what $x$ is.

Comment: OK i understand the result for $1 \le x \le 2$, but what about the answer for $2 \le x \le 3$? as it will not be an obvious integral

Comment: $\int_0^x = \int_0^1 +\int_1^2 + \int_2^x$. The integrand in the middle integral is zero because $f_X\equiv 0$ on $(1,2)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$F(x)=\frac12.\text{length of }(-\infty,x]\cap([0,1]\cup[2,3])$

Discern cases.

Formally "length of" means here "the Lebesguemeasure of".